# Express finalhandler cannot 404 after headers sent

Tags: node.js, express

I have an express app and i have added new route:

this is the route:

```
var router = require('express').Router();

router.post('/',function (req, res, next) {
  res.send("Ok");
});

module.exports = router;
```

now on every request that i make to this post route im getting at the express log:

`finalhandler cannot 404 after headers sent`

When making calls to DB the finalhandler does send 404 for every requst,

so im guessing that there is some kind of race with my functions and the finalhandler

anyone have anyidea?

UPDATE:

This is the index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');

var _ = require('underscore');
var stringUtils = require("underscore.string");

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(config.mongoUrl);
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(expressValidator());

var middleware = require('./middleware/authentication-middleware');
app.use(middleware.allowCrossDomains);
app.all('*', loginMiddlewareSkip);

var skipAuthPaths = ['/auth/fb', '/auth/login', '/auth/signup',     '/auth/forgot', '/auth/reset'];
function loginMiddlewareSkip(req, res, next) {
    if (stringUtils.startsWith(req.path, "/auth") || req.path ==     '/status'){ 
        return next();
    }

    middleware.ensureAuthenticated(req,res,next);
    next();
}

app.use('/passport', require('./routes/passport'));
app.use('/auth', require('./routes/authenticate'));


app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + 3000);
});
```

The file above is the `routes/passport`, and the auth file is working fine

Comment: Need to post more code.

Comment: @TannerFaulkner I have added the index js

Comment: Where's `finalhandler`?

Comment: @TannerFaulkner Its not mine.. It is an express dependency

Answer (score 1):

Ok the problem was with one of my middle wares:

in my `loginMiddlewareSkip` function i was calling 
`middleware.ensureAuthenticated(req,res,next)` if the path need an authentication, inside that function i was calling `next()` if authentication is successfull and as you can see i was calling next() again after calling the `ensureAuthenticated` function.

removing the `next()` from `loginMiddlewareSkip` solved the problem